# Django - null ForeignKey

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, foreign-keys

I have class SubForum with ForeignKey to self - parent:

```
class Forum(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    url = models.URLField()

class SubForum(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    orginal_id = models.IntegerField()

    forum = models.ForeignKey('Forum')
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True)
```

I want to allow for null and blank enteries - I saw examples that this is a proper way to do that.

In sql view everything is ok:

```
BEGIN;CREATE TABLE "main_forum" (
    "id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "name" varchar(200) NOT NULL,
    "url" varchar(200) NOT NULL
)
;
CREATE TABLE "main_subforum" (
    "id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "name" varchar(200) NOT NULL,
    "orginal_id" integer NOT NULL,
    "forum_id" integer NOT NULL REFERENCES "main_forum" ("id"),
    "parent_id" integer
)
;COMMIT;
```

In `parent_id` field there is no `NOT NULL`, but when I want to add new SubForum using admin panel without setting parent i get error:

`Cannot assign None: "SubForum.parent" does not allow null values.`

What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made some changes, reverted it back and now everything is working fine... and I don't see any difference with code that I posted here...

Should I delete question?

Comment: Did you by any chance not updatedb prior to finding that it didn't work.  Then in your efforts to solve the problem you ran the updatedb and your database was updated?

Comment: No you shouldn't delete it. One year later it was a good example for me.